# setTimeout in javascript does not show updated value

Tags: javascript, settimeout

why am I getting the outpupt 10 instead of 20. Why the setTimeout is not taking the latest value?

```
var a=10;
function foo(myvar){
  console.log(myvar);
}

setTimeout(foo,1000,a);
a=20;
```

if I put setTimeout in a loop then it consoles the latest value

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function log() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

3 3 3

Comment: `setTimeout(foo,1000,a);` you're effectively doing `setTimeout(foo,1000,10);` - primitives get passed as values - and in the second code ... `i` is `3` by the time all timeouts run ...

Comment: if, however, you did `setTimeout(function log(i) { console.log(i); }, 1000, i);` then you get 1,2,3

Comment: really, the two pieces of code are very different

Comment: the loop isn't what makes it different ... the way you call the function, and what the function logs, is what makes the difference

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `setTimeout` thread was initialized when the value for variable `a` is 10. There after you updated the value of variable `a`. But the value of parameter is still the old value `10`.

```js
var a = 10;
function foo(myvar) {
  console.log('Value for param ', myvar);
  console.log('Value for a ', a );
  console.log('Thread Executed');
}
console.log('Thread Started');
setTimeout(foo, 1000, a);
a = 20;
console.log('Variable Updated');
```

What is happening in the other case was you are logging the value of the index `i` which is in the for loop. At the time of execution of console, the value of i will be the last value, which is `3`

Answer (score 1):

One issue is - you're not comparing like for like code

```js
var a=10;
function foo(myvar){
  console.log(myvar);
}

setTimeout(foo,10,a);
a=20;
```

is comparable to

```js
var i;
function log(myvar) {
    console.log(myvar);
}
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(log, 10, i);
}
```

Whereas

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function log() {
      console.log(i);
  }, 10);
}
```

Is exactly equivalent to

```js
var i;
function log() {
    console.log(i);
}
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(log, 10);
}
```

and comparable to

```js
var a=10;

function foo(){
  console.log(a);
}

setTimeout(foo,10);
a=20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `a` by value in the call to `setTimeout()`. Therefore no matter how many times you change the value of `a` after calling `setTimeout()` you'd not get any of the new values.

The following snippet would work:

```
var a=10;
function foo(){
  console.log(a);
}

setTimeout(foo,1000);
a=20;
```

Because `a` is captured as part of the closure(`foo()`)'s calling context. Notice that `a` is not passed to `setTimeout()` explicitly.

The second example you gave appears to work to you but it is actually exactly the same as the original sample it's just that you pass three different values - 1, 2, and 3 - to three consecutive calls to `setTimeout()`. If you added an `if`-statement inside the loop to ensure that you only call `setTimeout()` when `i == 1` you'd see exactly the same behavior as in your first snippet.